# how can python csv.reader() able to read or exempt (") inside (" ")

Tags: python

on my csv/txt file there are multiple text like ("UMBRELLA 21"")
COL 50ML will be displayed but the next line error

```
icode,"COL 50ML",0,        ,        ,        ,1370,"cat1",1,"ecode","O"

icode,"UMBRELLA 21"",0,        ,        ,        ,0,"cat2",1,"ecode","O"
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/usern/Desktop/test3.py", line 18, in 
    if x[5] == '        ':
IndexError: list index out of range
```

```
import csv

file = csv.reader((open("C:\\Users\\usern\\Desktop\\ref\\data.txt","r")).readlines())

for data in file:
    x = data
    data1 = x[0]
    data2 = x[1]
    data2 = data2.replace("'","CHAR(39)")
    data3 = x[2]
    if x[3] == '        ':
        x[3] = '0000-00-00'
    data4 = x[3]
    if x[4] == '        ':
        x[4] = '0000-00-00'
    data5 = x[4]
    if x[5] == '        ':
        x[5] = '0000-00-00'
    data6 = x[5]
    data7 = x[6]
    data8 = x[7]
    data9 = x[8]
    data10 = x[9]
    data11 = x[10]
    print(str(data1)+','+str(data2)+','+str(data3)+','+str(data4)+','+str(data5)+','+str(data6)+','+str(data7)+','+str(data8)+','+str(data9)+','+str(data10)+','+str(data11))
```

Comment: Is that an exact line from the file, including the parens? Can you post the full traceback?

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. Please provide details on how to reproduce the error. Also, please provide the entire stacktrace in the question details.

Comment: i change the post please take a look thank you , im just trying / studying python

Comment: Is there really a blank 2nd line in the file?

Comment: icode,"COL 50ML",0,        ,        ,        ,1370,"cat1",1,"ecode","O"
icode,"UMBRELLA 21"",0,        ,        ,        ,0,"cat2",1,"ecode","O"

no blank 2nd line

Comment: i think the problem is on "UMBRELLA 21"" because of (21") , csv.reader might read it as ("UMBRELLA 21") then the (") on the end might cause the problem, but how can i solve it?

Comment: How are you able to call `readlines()`? That's a file method, but not a `csv.reader` method.

Comment: Why do you do `x = data`? Why not just `for x in file:` if that's the variable you want to use?

Answer (score 0):

In CSV format, putting two quotes adjacent is one of the ways to have nested quotes in a field. So the quotes after `UMBRELLA 21` don't end the field, it ends at the next `"` followed by a `,`.

As a result, the line is parsed as the following list:

```
[
    'icode', 
    'UMBRELLA 21",0,        ,        ,        ,0,cat2"', 
    '1', 
    'ecode', 
    'O'
]
```

Since this only has 5 fields, you get an error when you try to access `x[5]`.

If you want the string `UMBRELLA 21"` in the second field, the CSV line should be:

```
icode,"UMBRELLA 21""",0,        ,        ,        ,0,"cat2",1,"ecode","O"
```

The `""` becomes a single `"` after parsing, and the next `"` ends the field.

You could also use the `escapechar` option to `csv.reader()`, and escape the quote:

```
icode,"UMBRELLA 21\"",0,        ,        ,        ,0,"cat2",1,"ecode","O"
```

```
file = list(csv.reader((open("C:\\Users\\usern\\Desktop\\ref\\data.txt","r"), escapchar='\\'))
```

Comment: Please use complete sentences. I don't know what you're trying to say with that.

Comment: it doesnt parsed like this? [ 'icode', 'UMBRELLA 21"', '0', ' ' , ' ' , ' ' , '0', 'cat2', '1', 'ecode', 'O' ]

Comment: it try "UMBRELLA 21"""and it gave me an output UMBRELLA 21CHAR(34)

Comment: do i need to change / replace all  in the second field with (") on my csv/txt file? can i do that with python? cause csv file has a thousand of lines?

Comment: `chr(34)` is the `"` character.

Comment: How are you creating the CSV? If you use a CSV library it should automatically escpe or double the quotes.